# A way to group instances of VST plug-in with different formats, but the same algorithm

Tags: vst

I'm making a window showing all available plug-ins on the user's system. I want to group VST plug-ins to a visual bundles with common name in a one column and all available formats (like mono, stereo, etc.) in a separate column. Here is an example:

```
|  TrueVerb | Mono, Stereo     |
|  UM226    | Stereo, 5.0, 5.1 |
```

I see ProTools does something similar. I think it is because AAX plug-ins have separate unique ids for product and instance that could be used for such sort of things. But VST and VST3 SDKs don't provide anything similar. Though VST SDK provide "product name" of plug-in instance, it is not included in VST3 SDK.

Is there a way to tell whether certain instances represent same algorithm (i.e. product) with different format (width), except for parsing a plug-in name?